# Casting Frame Layout to ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In an Eclipse Android Application I have a page that displays a fragment in the top half with a "ViewPager" below.

I want to switch the position, so I have the ViewPager above the fragment:  in my XML I move the "ViewPager" code block above the "Frame-Layout" code block.

It doesn't work.  I get the error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated.

This XML code works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/fragment_container_mental"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:background="#ffff76"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">       
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

This XML Code throws the error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">       
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/fragment_container_mental"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:background="#ffff76"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Java code:

```
package com.winid.mentalapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.winid.mentalapp.Patient_Fragment_Comments;
import com.winid.mentalapp.Patient_Fragment_Dental;
import com.winid.mentalapp.Patient_Fragment_GFX1;
import com.winid.mentalapp.Patient_Fragment_GFX2;
import com.winid.mentalapp.Patient_Fragment_GFX3;
import com.winid.mentalapp.Patient_Fragment_GFX4;
import com.winid.mentalapp.Patient_Fragment_GFX5;
import com.winid.mentalapp.Patient_Fragment_PEDG1;
import com.winid.mentalapp.Patient_Fragment_PhotoGPS;
import com.winid.mentalapp.Patient_Fragment_UserDef;
import com.winid.mentalapp.MyPageAdapter;
import com.winid.mentalapp.R;
import com.winid.mentalapp.adapter.Patient_TabsPagerAdapter;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import  android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AntRestAddDetail extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener, ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private Patient_TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles

    private String[] tabs = { "Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Dd", "Ee", "Ff", "Gg", "Hh", "Ii"}
    public Intent i;

    public String t1="", t2="", t3="", t4="", t5="", t6="", t7="", t8="", t9="", t10="";
    public String t11="", t12="", t13="", t14="", t15="", t16="", t17="", t18="", t19="", t20="";
    public String t21="", t22="", t23="", t24="", t25="", t26="", t27="", t28="", t29="", t30="";
    public String t31="", t32="";

    MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.antrestadddetail);

        i = getIntent();

        List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
        pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new Patient_TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));            
        }

        //String RecNumb = i.getExtras().getString("id");

        // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
        Patient_Fragment_Mental firstFragment = new Patient_Fragment_Mental();

        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container_mental, firstFragment).commit();

         // on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

            public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            }

            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // on tab selected
                // show respected fragment view
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
    /*
    private List<Fragment> getFragments(){      
        List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();       
        //fList.add(Treatment_Fragment_AnteriorResto.newInstance("Fragment 1"));
        fList.add(MyListFragment.newInstance("Fragment 1"));
        fList.add(Treatment_Fragment_Crown.newInstance("Fragment 2"));  
        fList.add(Treatment_Fragment_Extraction.newInstance("Fragment 3"));
        fList.add(Treatment_Fragment_PostResto.newInstance("Fragment 4"));
        fList.add(Treatment_Fragment_Options.newInstance("Fragment 5"));    
        fList.add(Patient_Fragment_PhotoGPS.newInstance("Fragment 6"));
        fList.add(Patient_Fragment_PEDG1.newInstance("Fragment 7"));
        fList.add(Patient_Fragment_Comments.newInstance("Fragment 8")); 
        fList.add(Patient_Fragment_UserDef.newInstance("Fragment 9"));  
        return fList;
    }
    */

    private List<Fragment> getFragments(){      
        List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();       
        fList.add(Patient_Fragment_PEDG1.newInstance("Fragment 1"));
        fList.add(Patient_Fragment_Comments.newInstance("Fragment 2"));
        fList.add(Treatment_Fragment_Options.newInstance("Fragment 3"));    
        fList.add(Patient_Fragment_PhotoGPS.newInstance("Fragment 4"));
        fList.add(Patient_Fragment_UserDef.newInstance("Fragment 5"));  
        return fList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());        
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the java code where you use the elements? Maybe you get the view by id and you didn't change it accordingly. Also the stack trace would be useful.

Comment: Here is the java code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that sometimes when I reverse the order of some views in my XML, the **id**s do not update to match.  Try doing a clean build, which regenerates all of the **id**s, and run your project again.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  That seems to have solved the problem.  No more error.  But I will have to change formatting as only the ViewPager is showing now.